# Efficient way to subtract values in two HashMaps by key

Tags: java, hashmap

I am wondering how to efficiently subtract the values of two maps when their keys match. Currently I have 2 `HashMap<String,Integer>` and do it like this:

```
for (String key: map1.keySet()){
   if (map2.keySet().contains(key)){
       //subtract
   }
}
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: For "subtract" you mean delete all the stuff in map1 that is also in map2, or perform arithmetic subtraction between the values that have the same key?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by subtract: are you writing the results to a third map? Are you mutating the first or second map? Also, what is the nature of the key? Are they Comparable?

Comment: By substract I mean: if I have a ("Test", 6) and a ("Test", 2), I want to put my ("Test", 4) (6-2) in another map. The keys are Strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theoretically speaking, this is about as fast as it can be done unless you can somehow do a faster than O(n) way of finding the matching keys between the two `HashMap`s.

- Iterate over keys in first map's `keySet()` - O(n)

  - See if key is in other map - O(1)
  - Do your operation - O(1)

Comment: You might optimize a bit by iterating over the smaller of both maps.

Comment: @Paŭlo  yup, that's a good point and that'd be especially important for smaller sets or for where one set differs in size by an order of magnitude.  From a strictly theoretical (big-O) standpoint though, it's unimportant.

Comment: Yeah, now that I think about it, it seems this is as fast as it gets. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Realise this is an old thread but do check out guava from google

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Maps

You can use Map.difference and then get the entries in common, only in left, right etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think there isn't a better method *unless* you use a different approach, and/or different data structures. You can for example create a class named `ValuePair` that can contain (up to) two values, which represent the values you are currently storing in two different maps, but you instead store all the pairs in a single map, and when it comes to "subtract" you can iterate in a single set of keys. Please note that a pair can be incomplete, so that no subtraction is done.

But that's probabily overkill.

Answer (score -1):

have you considered using Apache Commons Collections?

```
CollectionUtils.subtract( collection1, collection2 );
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this subtracts one collection from another, it doesn't subtract the elements of the collection that share a key.

Comment: @Daniel: It wasn't clear. Upvoted because Liv gave a reasonable answer.

Comment: I think Azshara wants to subtract the actual values, not one collection from another

Comment: @alpian: I too interpreted it that way. But Liv's interpretation wasn't totally out of scope, and deserves respect.

Comment: I thought the question was completely clear.  Besides, `Map` does not even extend the `Collection` interface, so this answer is just plainly wrong.

Comment: wow, sorry, didn't mean to cause any arguments here :) I agree though that in the light of new comments/clarifications my answer is not what you're looking for.

Comment: @Giacomo: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87487/sympathy-upvotes-revisited-what-should-i-do